# How to display True & False for 1 & NULL

Tags: sql-server

In my query I am able to get column values as 1 and NULL. I would like to display True & False for 1 & NULL?

```
/*Declare Variable*/  
DECLARE @Pivot_Column [nvarchar](max);  
DECLARE @Query [nvarchar](max);  

/*Select Pivot Column*/  
SELECT @Pivot_Column= COALESCE(@Pivot_Column+',','')+ QUOTENAME(PracticeLocationServiceCode) FROM  
(SELECT DISTINCT [PracticeLocationServiceCode] FROM PracticeLocationService)Tab  

/*Create Dynamic Query*/  
SELECT @Query='
;WITH ServiceOffered
AS
(
SELECT PracticeLocationID, '+@Pivot_Column+'FROM   
(SELECT PracticeLocationID, PracticeLocationServiceCode,CAST(ServiceFlag AS INT) ServiceFlag FROM PracticeLocationService )Tab1  
PIVOT  
(  
MAX(ServiceFlag) FOR [PracticeLocationServiceCode] IN ('+@Pivot_Column+')) AS Tab2
) 
SELECT REGION,LocationShortName,GLCODE,C.* FROM ServiceOffered C 
INNER JOIN VWLOCATIONS V ON V.PracticeLocationID = C.PracticeLocationID
ORDER BY REGION,LocationShortName
'
/*Execute Query*/  
EXEC  sp_executesql  @Query
```

Comment: `CASE WHEN field = 1 THEN 'True' WHEN field IS NULL THEN 'False' ELSE 'Oops!' END`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I have the feild value like @Pivot_Column, I should get the values dynamically but not hard code vales. I have table variable values like General,general
emergency
inpatient
outpatient
wardno
 I am able to use pivot and get in horizantal but i need to get dynamically

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server does not have the Boolean data type. There are no built-in values `true` and `false`. One alternative is to use strings `'true'` and `'false'`, but these are strings just like any other string. Often the [`bit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/bit-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) type is used instead of Boolean as it can only have values `1` and `0`. Typically 1 is used for "true" and 0 for "false". It is still an integer type, though. Boolean logic will not work. For example, `if (CONVERT(bit, 1) and CONVERT(bit, 1))...` is not legal syntax.

Likely the best option is to use a CASE and return the requisite strings, as @Akina commented:

```
CASE
    WHEN TheColumn = 1 THEN 'True'
    WHEN TheColumn IS NULL THEN 'False'
    ELSE 'Oops!'
END
```